# Internal server error while installing odoo 10 in windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, odoo-10

I am facing this problem while installing odoo 10 in windows. This error occurs while running odoo 10 in browser. I have seen log file and it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 249, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1308, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1282, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1446, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1368, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1530, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1498, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 333, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 635, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 518, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 586, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect

OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Is this the first time you install odoo ?

Comment: This is first time installation in windows.

Comment: Try starting manually postgresql service to see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting appears to be from Postgres not currently running, rather than an authentication error as you're presumed. The PSQL client or whatever PG client you're using is attempting to establish a connection on the default port but nothing is there.

If Postgres isn't currently running, try finding it (Via CTRL-Alt-Delete). If it's running, try terminating it and starting it up again. Hopefully that fixes the problem... Otherwise your port 5432 might be blocked for some reason.

If all fails, I am still skeptical the parentheses could cause this error because it's not an authentication error. Try to reinstall Postgres with a clean install.

Or you can get all port open in windows by using  `netstat -an` in `cmd`

Comment: Ok I'll try that command. Rest all the solutions i have tried but didn't get any solution. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this again because I recently faced this issue which says **"Internal server error"** with odoo 11 using in windows 10.
This is because either odoo service or postgres service is not running. Now what we need to do is:

1. Go to **Search** in windows, which can be accessed via right click on windows symbol on the bottom left corner of the screen.
2. Search for **services**. You can see a services settings on searching for services. Click on it.
3. Now inside services, search for **odoo service**. Click on it. You will get 3 option. i,e to **a. Start, b. stop & c. restart**. on the left tab of window.
4. Click on **restart**. Wait until it says running.
5. Repeat steps **3 & 4** for **postgres service**.

Hope it helps to someone who face this issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you must first install pgAdmin and create the user you specified during flectra installation. Then, you must grant all privileges on the user that it creates. Use tabs for assign access and set password.

You can find more detailed information in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XiwEi92hgQ